# Plotting ECDF of values using R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the ECDF of 'x' based on the observed frequency of 'x' given in 'freq'. The data frame is shown below.

```
    x   freq
1   1    165
2   2    898
3   3    289
4   4   2220
5   5    535
6   6   1885
7   7   2344
8   8  36550
9   9    884
10 10   1480
11 11   1132
12 12   2733
13 13   1828
14 14  11152
15 15   6379
16 16 304355
```

The following code snippet seems to generate what I want, but I was wondering if this is the *right/better/idiomatic* way to do this.

```
ggplot(transform(freq.data, ecdf = cumsum(freq)/sum(freq.data$freq)), aes(x, ecdf)) + geom_step()
```

Comment: It looks like `ggplot2` has an ECDF: [`stat_ecdf()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_ecdf.html). But your data might not be in the right format to use it. Try passing it the data before you do the frequency counts.

Comment: The problem I face is that if I face 'freq' to stat_ecdf or ecdf or similar functions that compute the ECDF by sorting the values in 'freq' and computing the ECDF and that's not what I want. Looks like I have to reshape the data to a different format and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- with(df, rep(x, freq))
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = x), aes(x)) + stat_ecdf()
```

Comment: It is a bit slow and I believe that's because of the replication of 'X' based on 'freq'. Is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: You could see what happens if you round it to the nearest decade: `x <- with(df, rep(x, round(freq,-1) )). I don't think that will distort the shape very much. (it didn't seem very slow on my 6 year old-Mac. Maybe you need a new machine?)